# How to implement twitter follow without showing popup

Tags: javascript

i am displaying list of twitter users on my website and twitter follow button against each user and i want when some visitor clicks that follow button that user get followed by visitor without opening twitter popup screen. How can i implement. Thanks in advance fro any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As your question looks now, it is far too broad to be answered in a meaningful way in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't affect this functionality in the Twitter follow buttons - it's essentially a confirmation step for the user. It wouldn't be a very nice user experience to click a few buttons on a site and unexpectedly be following a bunch of people they didn't mean to.

If you've had them authenticate your site as a Twitter app and have an access token, https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create

Comment: i am trying to implement this [http://www.staged.com/members/social_twitter_builder.php#/find_users/24837/](http://www.staged.com/members/social_twitter_builder.php#/find_users/24837/)

Comment: @faisi That requires a login.

Comment: thanks a lot, this link you provided helped me a lot.