# Twitter Follow widget without opening intent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I want to use the twitter "follow-button" widget, but, instead of opening an intent everytime a user clicks on it to view the targetted user, i want it to follow the targetted user directly without opening the intent. Is that possible?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?
https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button

> The user interaction flow for the Follow Button was designed to be as
> streamlined as possible and easy to use for developers, website owners
> and users. There are two simple Follow Button flows, depending on the
> user’s current state:
>
> Signed in to twitter.com: When clicking the Follow Button, the user
> will instantly be following the target user.
>
> Not signed in to
> twitter.com: This will open the Intent box and prompt the user to sign
> in to twitter.com.

Comment: Yes I have, but the thing is, when a user clicks on that button "a window popsup" and the user has to follow the targetted user from that window.
In My solution, I want to follow the targetted user without opening that window.
Do you know of any approaches?

Comment: No, it displays the popup even if the user is logged in.

Comment: Have you seen the discussion here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403785/how-to-implement-twitter-follow-without-showing-popup